# Regex for validating NUMBER(m,n)

Tags: regex

I have the following regex to validate the incoming data for the column datatype NUMBER(9,2) with the +/- prefix as an optional one.

```
[+-]?(?:[0-9]{1,7})?(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?
```

Allowed values

```
+1
+1.1
-0.1
+.1
1
1.1
0.1
1
-1
-1.1
-.1
1111111.11
+1111111.11
-1111111.11
```

Failing cases

```
+
-
```

But it also accepts only the +/- symbols since the capturing groups are all made optional. How do we overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Updated***

Since all capturing groups are optional it'll inevitably match a single `[+-]` if occurs
Use the following regex pattern:

```
^[+-]?(\d{1,7}|(?=\.))(\.\d{1,2})?
```

https://regex101.com/r/4GIOga/5

Comment: I think you want `[+-]?\d{1,7}(\.\d{1,2})?` as I don't think OP wants only numbers 7 longer, but accepts number up to 7 digits. And with

Comment: First digit part seems to also be optional in OP question.

Comment: @Niitaku, check my update, it will cover all allowed values

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks for the response. What if I don't need to concentrate more on m,n rather than just the format? Removing {1,7} or {1,2} will not work I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead after the sign class to indicate that you allow them only if it is followed by anything:

```
^[+-]?(?=.+)(?:[0-9]{1,7})?(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

If you test all the numbers at once, you'll need to set the multiline modifier.

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/QDJMty/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
^{-|\+}?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

This would work for every case you have put up.